# Vector equation of a line through point and line

Tags: vectors

The question is:

Find a vector equation of a line that contains $(1,-2,1)$ and is perpendicular to the line through $r=\langle 2-t,3t,1+4t\rangle$.

This was my method:

$$1(2-t)-2(3t)+(1+4t)=0$$

$$t=1$$

Plug into the original $r$ line gives $\langle 1,3,5\rangle$.

New line: $r = \langle 1,-2,1\rangle  + t\langle 1,3,5\rangle $

Is my method correct?

Comment: Check for yourself: your line has direction $(1,3,5)$ and the given line has direction $(-1,3,4)$.  Are these perpendicular?

Comment: Can you help me find the correct answer? I am not sure what to do. @David

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to do this, here is one.

The required line will go through the point $(1,-2,1)$ and also through the point $(2-t,3t,1+4t)$ for some value of $t$.  The line will therefore have direction
$$(2-t,3t,1+4t)-(1,-2,1)=(1-t,2+3t,4t)\ .$$
You need to find the value of $t$ which makes this direction perpendicular to $(-1,3,4)$; you will then know the direction of the required line, and you should be able to finish the job from there.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A line through (0,0,0) that is parallel to the desired line is (-t, 3t, 4t).  You can shift this to go through your desired point.

Comment: That's parallel to the given line.  Unless I misunderstood the question, the OP wants a perpendicular.